# ssh key not working while starting hadoop service

Tags: hadoop, ssh

when i start hadoop daemon i got following error

```
[hdp@localhost ~]$  start-all.sh
WARNING: Attempting to start all Apache Hadoop daemons as hdp in 10 seconds.
WARNING: This is not a recommended production deployment configuration.
WARNING: Use CTRL-C to abort.
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
localhost: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
Starting datanodes
localhost: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
Starting secondary namenodes [localhost.localdomain]
localhost.localdomain: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
Starting resourcemanager
Starting nodemanagers
localhost: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
```

Comment: Are you running SSH server? Can you please try `ssh localhost`? In other words, this isn't a Hadoop problem

Comment: you  had to configure SSH from  this machine to itself.